# C++ Exception throw

Tags: c++, exception, throw

I made a program and when i debug it crashes and shows me the error:

Exception thrown at 0x0FC93AA8 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x8BADB618.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Any ideas what could it be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class bendraAbonentoInformacija
{
public:
string vardasPavarde;
string asmensKodas;
string adresas;
double suma;
string tiekejas;

};
class elektra : public bendraAbonentoInformacija
{
public:
    double tarifas;
    int skaitiklisNuo;
} rect;
class siuksles : public bendraAbonentoInformacija
{
public:
int kvadratura;
};
class vanduo : public bendraAbonentoInformacija
{
public:
int saltasVanduo;
int sildymas;
};

void nuskaitymas(int& i, bendraAbonentoInformacija masyvas[], elektra elektrosMasyvas[], siuksles siuksliuMasyvas[], vanduo vandensMasyvas[])
{
ifstream duomenuNuskaitymas;
duomenuNuskaitymas.open ("duomenys.txt");
string vardasPavarde;
string asmensKodas;
string adresas;
double suma;
string tiekejas;
int tarifas;
double skaitliukas;
int kvadratura;
int saltasVanduo;
int sildymas;

i = 0;

if (duomenuNuskaitymas.is_open())
{
    while (!duomenuNuskaitymas.eof())
    {

        duomenuNuskaitymas >> masyvas[i].vardasPavarde >> masyvas[i].asmensKodas >> masyvas[i].adresas >> masyvas[i].suma >> masyvas[i].tiekejas;

        if (masyvas[i].tiekejas == "Vilniaus energija")
        {
            duomenuNuskaitymas >> elektrosMasyvas[i].tarifas >> elektrosMasyvas[i].skaitiklisNuo;

        }
        else if (masyvas[i].tiekejas == "Kauno svara")
        {
            duomenuNuskaitymas >> siuksliuMasyvas[i].kvadratura;
        }
        else if (masyvas[i].tiekejas == "Rokiskio vandenys")
        {
            duomenuNuskaitymas >> vandensMasyvas[i].saltasVanduo >> vandensMasyvas[i].sildymas;
        }

        i++;

    }

    duomenuNuskaitymas.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file";

}

void PaieskaPagalAsmensKodaIrRikiavimas(int i, bendraAbonentoInformacija masyvas[])
{
string AsmensKodas;
bendraAbonentoInformacija abonentas[1000];
bendraAbonentoInformacija Kintamasis;
int k = 0;

cout << "Iveskite asmens, kurio saskaitos ieskote, asmens koda: ";
cin >> AsmensKodas;

cout << "Rasta informacija:" << endl;

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    if (AsmensKodas == masyvas[j].asmensKodas)
    {
        cout << masyvas[j].vardasPavarde << masyvas[j].adresas << masyvas[j].asmensKodas << masyvas[j].suma;
        abonentas[k] = masyvas[j];
        k++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    if (abonentas[i].suma < abonentas[i + 1].suma)
    {
        Kintamasis = abonentas[i];
        abonentas[i] = abonentas[i + 1];
        abonentas[i + 1] = Kintamasis;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    cout << abonentas[i].vardasPavarde << abonentas[i].suma;
}

}


int main()
{

int i;
bendraAbonentoInformacija masyvas[1000];
elektra elektrosMasyvas[1000];
siuksles siuksliuMasyvas[1000];
vanduo vandensMasyvas[1000];

nuskaitymas(i, masyvas, elektrosMasyvas, siuksliuMasyvas, vandensMasyvas);
//PaieskaPagalAsmensKodaIrRikiavimas(i,masyvas);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I might be able to over come the language barrier here, but without the input file it's hard to reproduce.

Comment: You may try to put the offending code into a `try { ... } catch(...) {}` block, but I think you should rather find the reason for the access violation. Since you already debugged your program, could you mark the line in your program that causes the access violation?

Answer (score 0):

The array access in `nuskaitymas` may go out of bounds if sufficiently many iterations of the while loop are executed.  Consider using a dynamically sized data type like `std::vector`.

The use of `std::ifstream` can be improved as well.   Instead of `!duomenuNuskaitymas.eof()`, use `!duomenuNuskaitymas`.  Additionally, explicit closing of `std::ifstream` is unnecessary.  This will be executed when the object goes out of scope and the destructor is called.  Finally, I would check that reading in from the `std::ifstream` is successful.  If it is not, then you would both fail to read in new values, while simultaneously incrementing the index and never reaching the end of file.